# Categorizing Python violin plots by 5-year intervals

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
year      count
1982      -10
1983      -3
1984      2
1984      12
1985      4
...
2007      3
2008      10
2009      -1
2009      0
2009      4
```

(the values are arbitrarily edited)

I'm trying to create a violin plot with x-axis being `year` and y-axis being `count`, which is executed via the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,10))

ax = sns.violinplot(x="year", y='count', ax=ax,
                    data=df, palette="muted", split=True)

ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Number')

plt.show()
```

This returns:
[image]

As shown, this is quite difficult to interpret as there are too many categories. I'd like to group the years into 5-year intervals. I tried something like:

```
axes.violinplot(dataset = [df[df.year < 1990]["count"].values,
                           df[df.year > 1990 & df.year < 1996]["count"].values,
                           df[df.year > 1995 & df.year < 2001]["count"].values,
                           df[df.year > 2000 & df.year < 2006]["count"].values,
                           df[df.year > 2005]["count"].values])
```

but this returns an error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How can I group the `year` data into 5-year intervals in my violin plot?

Comment: I would look into [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select rows from a dataframe based on multiple conditions, you need to put parenthesis around each condition:

```
dataset = [df[df.year < 1990]["count"].values,
                           df[(df.year > 1990) & (df.year < 1996)]["count"].values,
                           df[(df.year > 1995) & (df.year < 2001)]["count"].values,
                           df[(df.year > 2000) & (df.year < 2006)]["count"].values,
                           df[df.year > 2005]["count"].values]
```